# What kind of clothes does a new born need to wear in summers?

Tags: infant, clothes

The daytime temperature here is 45 degree Celsius in summers.
We have a ceiling fan. We also have covered our window panes with Aluminum foil to reduce the impact of heat.

So, what kind of (and how many) clothes does a new born need to wear in this environment so that he doesn't get sick from either heat or cold?

P.S. I can't keep him naked always.

Comment: see also http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/7645/are-clothes-needed-for-a-newborn/7646#7646 for purposes clothes serve - I would suggest the lightest weight cloth possible, but cover much of their skin in order to keep them protected from things other than heat or cold.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Light clothing.  My daughter was born at the height of summer around here which generally averages in the mid to upper 90s degrees Fahrenheit (32+ degrees Celcius).  Granted, not quite as hot as 113 degrees Fahrenheit...

Onesies are your best friend.  Short-sleeved onesies with no legs like [these](http://www.gerberchildrenswear.com/Short-Sleeve-Onesies%C2%AE-One-Piece-Underwear/6940343DRBN3,default,pd.html?start=4&cgid=gerber-onesiesbrand-neutral).  If your baby starts to get cold, you can always throw a light blanket over him or if he's too hot you can take the onesie off and allow him some time with just a diaper or naked.

If you're going to take him outside, make sure he's covered so that you protect his sensitive skin.  A wide-brimmed hat to protect his face, for example.  For little babies, it's sometimes easiest to keep them in their strollers so you can keep the sun off of them with either the attached sunshade or with a light blanket.

Baby-wearing can also be a good way to protect their skin from the sun when you're out as many of the typical newborn carries involve covering their whole bodies with the baby carrier.

Comment: The only problem with summer baby wearning is that many carriers, at least soft structured ones, are very warm for both mother and baby.

Comment: `Short-sleeved onesies with no legs` Are these supposed to be worn directly over the body, or the baby has to wear something under them too? (Referring to chest part)

Comment: Nothing underneath except a diaper. Cotton fabric is best.

Answer (score 3):

During hot summers, the general guidance is to keep them cool but covered from the sun. If you are filtering sunlight anyway, you don't need to worry so much about coverage from the sun, so clothe them in enough layers they feel comfortably warm.

As an example, in a hot Scottish summer (25 degrees C or more) we would just put a vest, a sun hat and a nappy on our babies, and give them quite a lot of time with no clothes at all. But in the evening we would add a blanket or layers. I would imagine that growing up in 45 degree summers would mean you and your child would require many more layers here, so you need to tailor the clothing to the individual, not necessarily the absolute temperature.

They will let you know when they are uncomfortable, and you will rapidly learn what their cry is for too hot, or too cold. This is an aspect new parents often worry about, but babies do communicate quite well, with different cries to let you know what they want.